# Shortcuts in gvim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, gvim

I'm trying to migrate from Windows to Linux and am having difficulties with the shortcuts in gvim.

For something as simple a copying you press "+y and I'm wondering

1)does order matter when pressing the buttons? I already found you don't need to hold down all 4 (including shift) keys at once

2)is there a simpler shortcut or a way to change this one?

3)why on Earth did the makers choose these keys to mean copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Vim doesn't support *chording*, i.e. pressing several keys simultaneously. It's only **one main key, plus a possible combination of modifier keys (i.e. <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>)**. So, you'd type <kbd>"</kbd>, then <kbd>+</kbd>, then <kbd>y</kbd> when you read `"+y`.

---

For stuff that you do frequently, there's a shortcut mechanism, called **mappings**. For example, to use <kbd>F2</kbd> instead:

```
:nnoremap <F2> "+y
```

You'll need to understand the *modes* of Vim. `:help map.txt` has all the information. If you just want mappings like most Windows applications (e.g. Ctrl+C for copy), add

```
:runtime mswin.vim
```

to your `~/.vimrc`, and you're done.

---

Why is `"+y` so difficult? Well, usually you use Vim's internal registers, mostly the *unnamed register*, and that's the quick and easy `y`. Vim is often used in the terminal or through an SSH connection, so interacting with the system's clipboard is not that common.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using system clipboard in vim. That means

- Anything yanked by <kbd>y</kbd> / <kbd>Y</kbd> / <kbd>x</kbd> / <kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>d</kbd> /.., will write to system clipboard.
- And also, anything was copied by <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> or something, will be pasted to vim by <kbd>p</kbd> / <kbd>P</kbd> / ...

The setting as below:

```
if has('win32') || has('win95') || has('win64')
    set clipboard+=unnamed
    set clipboard+=unnamedplus
else
    set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

More details can be found at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard and http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip21